# Can't find a file in maven automatic test

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

I have a directory in my test folder with all my JavaScript file need for my tests.

```
src/main
src/test
src/test/java
src/test/javascript
src/test/ressources
```

I have some tests in src/test/java that use some resources in src/test/javascript.
It is well working when i launch Junit test manually. But when i launch the Maven test goal. i have this :

```
 Couldn't read source file "src/test/javascript/envJsOptions.js": src\test\javascript\envJsOptions.js (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: give us your java code? how are you using js from junit?

Comment: I am using a Junit runner for Jasmine

Comment: i m sure you have seen this http://sourceforge.net/p/jasminerunner/wiki/Annotations/

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you are using js file in junit test

but just try using javascript/envJSOptions.js

src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources

all these folders can be considered to be in classpath (same level)

so the paths will be started from that point on, if you are using a resource as stream..